# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of undefined core.js:5967

Tags: angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

**Component.ts**

```
branches: any = [];
branchName: string; // any
ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.refreshBranchList();
    this.service.getBranchList().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.branches = response;
});
}
Search() {
if (this.branchName !== "") {
  this.branches = this.branches.filter((res: { branchName: string; }) => {
    return res.branchName.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.branchName.toLocaleLowerCase());
  })
} else if (this.branchName == "") {
  this.ngOnInit();
}
```

}

**Component.html**

```html
<div class="d-flex float-right">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here" [(ngModel)]="branchName" (ngModelChange)="Search()">
</div>
```

It is Searching the values as Expected. But there is an error in the console which I'm not familiar with. Is there anything I'm missing please tell me.

[image: error detail]

Comment: The error is speaking itself. Either `res.branchName` or `this.branchName` is undefined and it is not able to find function `.toLocaleLowerCase()` in it. try to add check if value exists before calling `.toLocaleLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to verify the value of `this.branchName`

Try this way:

```js
branches: any = [];
    branchName: string; // any
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // this.refreshBranchList();
        this.service.getBranchList().subscribe((response: any) => {
          this.branches = response;
    });
    }

    Search() {
      if (this.branchName && this.branchName !== "") {
        this.branches = this.branches.filter((res: { branchName: string; }) => {
        res.branchName? return res.branchName.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.branchName.toLocaleLowerCase()): return [];
      })
    } else if (this.branchName == "") {
      this.ngOnInit();
    }
  }
```

Comment: actually these ( ? ) not working so I tried it with if else for branchNames like this: if (res.branchName == "") {
          return res.branchName.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.branchName.toLocaleLowerCase());
        }
        else {
          return [];
        }

Answer (score 4):

try to change this

```
return res.branchName.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.branchName.toLocaleLowerCase());
```

to this

```
return res.branchName?.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.branchName?.toLocaleLowerCase());
```

Comment: The code is not working with these ?. I don't know why but thankyou for help

Comment: this.branchName?.toLowerCase() => ? this means if there is a branch name then call toLowerCase(). you're getting error because when you try to reach branchname branchname is undefined. Reconsider your logic your trying to reach branchname without initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

Like Nik said in his comment, either res.branchName or this.branchName is undefined.

So either define your objects if they are undefined or use the ?-operator for res?.branchName?.toLocaleLowerCase() and this.branchName?.toLocaleLowerCase(), if the view is rendered before your properties are assigned with a value.